# How to put minus (-) before some specific columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing 2000 columns, all are numeric variables, 
and I want to convert specific columns [whose names stars with X1COL,X2COL] from positive values to negative values

Before:

```
¦ 1COL1 ¦ 2COL ¦ 3COL ¦ X1COL ¦ 4COL ¦ X2COL ¦

    +      +       +      +      +       +
```

After:

```
¦ 1COL1 ¦ 2COL ¦ 3COL ¦ X1COL ¦ 4COL ¦ X2COL ¦

    +      +      +       -       +      -
```

Comment: `df$col <- -df$col` will make that column negative...if thats what you want

Comment: No it will convert all variables to negative,  I want specific columns whose variables are negative

Comment: First step: Use a regex to select the columns you want to multiply by -1.

Comment: Help me with the code.

Comment: @SutirthaThakur ... and by "help me with the code" you mean ["give me the code"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question)? Down vote (-1) from me for zero effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dplyr::mutate_at` allows to apply function on columns whose name matches regex, for example:

```r
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(
  X1COL = 1:3,
  X2COL = 1:3,
  X3COL = 1:3
)
df$`1COL` = 1:3
df$`2COL` = 1:3
df$`3COL` = 1:3

df
#   X1COL X2COL X3COL 1COL 2COL 3COL
# 1     1     1     1    1    1    1
# 2     2     2     2    2    2    2
# 3     3     3     3    3    3    3

# to convert all columns like "X.COL" to negative
# which means X1COL, X2COL, X3COL, ...
df %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("X.COL")), `-`)

#   X1COL X2COL X3COL 1COL 2COL 3COL
# 1    -1    -1    -1    1    1    1
# 2    -2    -2    -2    2    2    2
# 3    -3    -3    -3    3    3    3


# to convert all columns starts with "X1COL" or "X2COL" to negative
# which means X1COL.a, X2COL.b, X1COL.ab, X2COL.bc
df %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("^X(1|2)COL.*")), `-`)

#   X1COL X2COL X3COL 1COL 2COL 3COL
# 1    -1    -1     1    1    1    1
# 2    -2    -2     2    2    2    2
# 3    -3    -3     3    3    3    3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- your_dataframe # data

for (i in colnames(df)){
   if startsWith(i, 'X', ignore.case=TRUE) == TRUE{
       print(df$i*-1)
   else{
       print(df$i)
    }
  }
}
```

Creat you new data frame for the print statement then cbind it.